# Python/PySide: How to make a widget that will stay on top of the main window, but not cover up other widgets?

Tags: python, pyqt, window, pyside

So I have a script running inside another program (The Foundry's Hiero) and I'm just making a new QWidget object, and calling `self.show()`

Now, I can set it to `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)`, so my window will stay on top of the main window, even if you click on something in the main window.

The problem is, this is a sort of popup window that you configure settings in, and it triggers other QWidget popups. If I set my window to `WindowStaysOnTopHint`, those subdialogs that my widget triggers end up *beneath* my widget.

Is there a way in PySide/PyQt to make a window stay on top/keep focus from the main application window in particular, but not *everything*?

Comment: Perhaps you can set the newer popups "on top" too. This will open them on top of their parent widget..

Comment: On Linux you may have many on-top windows and current active on-top window should be shown above other on-top windows. I don't know if Windows may have many on-top windows. Maybe when you run new popup window you will have to unset on-top flag for original window and set it to popup window. And when you close popup window then you may have to set again on-top flag for original window.

Comment: @noEmbryo I would love to try to do something like that, but unfortunately my script pulls in widgets that are prebuilt in the main software I'm writing a plugin for. I only have control over my window, and then my window will pull in subwidgets from somwehere else, and THOSE widgets make new popup windows. It's a bit of an awkward situation

Comment: Unless I can figure out some way of detecting newer popups, and then sort of "injecting" them with a stay on top flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `QApplication.focusChanged` signal to raise your widget up when Hiero's main window is selected. Then you would just need to remove the `WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag.

I'm not familiar with Hiero's API, but I'm guessing you could try something like:

```
def raiseMyWidget(old, new):
    if new == hiero.ui.mainWindow():
        myWidget.raise_()
QtWidgets.QApplication.instance().focusChanged.connect(raiseMyWidget)
```

Hope this helps! You can take advantage of the old parameter or some other means to make sure that your widget isn't raised above the others as well.

Comment: This works beautifully! Thanks!

For anybody else here - I ended up needing to check that new.window() == hiero.ui.mainWindow(), since I was getting the widget that was clicked on as new - not the actual window.